# Connect SFDC with Other App, and this App with SFDC

Tags: rest-api, webservices, salesforce-id

I need send information to other aplication, and this application will send me the result.
In my case, we have a community with opportunitys. When the Opp is closed, user can click on a button that it will send the name, and other fields to external App. In this external App, user can see all opportunitys, when he finish, click on button and the App sends the opp with a field (check) with true value.

We will connect for REST API.
I think I need: Remote Site Setting, Connected App, and WS (apex class).
    * Remote Site Setting: to invoke the web address (the external APP)
    * Connected App: for recognize and authenicate the external app (consumer key and consumer secret)
    * WS (apex): http GET. A function that read paramethers and update the opp

My doubts are, this is enough? What is the url for the external application to connect to SFDC? In the first call (SFDC to App) it is necessary to send the token (consumerKey and consumer secret)?

Thanks

Regards
Rodol

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to look at the [Canvas Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm) for details, but it is designed to allow you to initiate a connection with an external site that can get a session ID and whatever data you would like the app to get, and perform bidirectional communication. This will require some development on the app side, obviously, but is probably the easiest path to your goal.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox. I´ve never done an integration with Canvas, I´ve some experience with REST API, that's why I commented doing it this way.

Comment: @Rodolfo You still use the REST API for the actual integration; the Canvas API provides some mechanisms for interacting with the Salesforce UI and authentication.